# Bootstrap Daterangepicker move range inputs to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using a basic bootstrap daterangepicker. However I need the range inputs (apply and cancel buttons) to be on the right side after the calendars.

Currently, it's on the left as so:

[image]

Is there any way that it is already programmed for me to easily move it to the right?

*UPDATE CODE*
I am using the basic code that they've provided.

```
<div id="reg-date" class="btn">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
    <span></span> 
    <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
```

and here is the script that i used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#reg-date span').html(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
      $('#reg-date').daterangepicker({
         opens: 'right'
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: @flolaloop Do you mean currently its on left? share the code as well.

Comment: @pratikwebdev ah yes! i've corrected my question

Comment: Are you using moment js as well?

Comment: @pratikwebdev yes i'm using moment.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are anticipating apply and cancel buttons on right side of control irrespective of calendar icon and caret to open datepicker controls. You could use simple code like this. It gives you the same result. Apply and cancel on right side of calendar controls

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
```

Also if you would like to work out through existing code you would need to update question with CSS and update screenshot with calendar and caret icon.